# Get specific columns using “with()” inside of another '

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i need to get specific columns in the 2 methods that is being chained inside 'with', but it doesnt work, how can i select specific columns in each method inside of the 'with' method.

```
Event::with('eventBookmakers.bookmakerInfo')->find(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible like this:

```
Event::with('eventBookmakers:column', 'eventBookmakers.bookmakerInfo:column')->find(2);
```

Remember to select the foreign key columns (e.g. `event_id`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change column name to what column you want to retrieve.

```
Event::with('eventBookmakers.bookmakerInfo:columnName')->where('id', 2)->get();
```

or

```
Event::with('eventBookmakers.bookmakerInfo:columnName')->find(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're selecting the two interrelated tables (relations) using dot `.` You may use `select()` and `with()` in a closure to add constraint and add the relations as well. So you'll end up with something like:

```
Event::with(['eventBookmakers' => function($bookmakers){
    $bookmakers->select('id', 'event_id')->with(['bookmakerInfo' => function($info) {
        $info->select('id', 'bookmaker_id');
    }]);
}])->find(2);
```

Note the `event_id` passed to the first select ensure the relationship is loaded between `Event` and `EventBookmaker`(you can replace it with the relation_id you use instead) and same thing with using `bookmaker_id` so that it may load relation between `Bookmaker` and `BookmakerInfo`